# How to establish communication between a computer java application and a android phone?

Tags: java, android, sockets, server, client

I have to do a project for the university. I have to connect the mobile phone (android application) with a java desktop project in order to exchange data.
below I propose what I have done for now:

Server1.java

```html
package com.pervasive;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Server1 {
    private static Thread Thread1;
    static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static PrintWriter output;
    private static BufferedReader input;

    public static final int SERVER_PORT = 6789;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
        Thread1.start();
    }

    static class Thread1 implements Runnable{
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

        Thread1() throws UnknownHostException {
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {
            Socket socket;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);
                System.out.println("Not connected!\nIP: " + inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\nPort: " + SERVER_PORT + "\n");
                try {
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    System.out.println("Connected\n");
                    new Thread(new Thread2()).start();
                } catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    private static class Thread2 implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                try {
                    final String message = input.readLine();
                    if(message != null){
                        System.out.println("Client: " + message + "\n");
                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static class Thread3 implements Runnable{
        private String message;
        Thread3(String message){this.message = message; }
        @Override
        public void run(){
            output.write(message);
            output.flush();
            System.out.println("Server: " + message + "\n");
        }

    }
}
```

While the following code is about the Android application.
MainActivity.java

```html
package com.example.clientapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Thread Thread1 = null;
    EditText etIP, etPort;
    TextView tvMessages;
    EditText etMessage;
    Button btnSend;
    String SERVER_IP;
    int SERVER_PORT;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        etIP = findViewById(R.id.etIP);
        etPort = findViewById(R.id.etPort);
        tvMessages = findViewById(R.id.tvMessages);
        etMessage = findViewById(R.id.etMessage);
        btnSend = findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        Button btnConnect = findViewById(R.id.btnConnect);
        btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tvMessages.setText("");
                SERVER_IP = etIP.getText().toString().trim();
                SERVER_PORT = Integer.parseInt(etPort.getText().toString().trim());
                Thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
                Thread1.start();
            }
        });
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = etMessage.getText().toString().trim();
                if (!message.isEmpty()) {
                    new Thread(new Thread3(message)).start();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private PrintWriter output;
    private BufferedReader input;

    public void OnReceiveMessage(View view) {

        output.write((String) tvMessages.getText());
    }

    class Thread1 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Socket socket;
            try {
                socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP), SERVER_PORT);
                output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tvMessages.setText("Connected\n");
                    }
                });
                new Thread(new Thread2()).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    class Thread2 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    final String message = input.readLine();
                    if (message != null) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                tvMessages.append("server: " + message + "\n");
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Thread1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
                        Thread1.start();
                        return;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Thread3 implements Runnable {
        private String message;
        Thread3(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            output.write(message);
            output.flush();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tvMessages.append("client: " + message + "\n");
                    etMessage.setText("");
                }
            });
        }
    }


}
```

The problem is the following: I can't connect them.
can you help me?

Comment: You should first tell in your own words what you have done. Or what your code should do. . After that you can post the code for it.

Comment: Are the two on the same network, are they public in the internet? Are firewalls properly configured? This is not really code-related but network infrastructure related